# PHP curl get outgoing headers

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to get curl outgoing headers? So, for example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer );
```

IS it possible to call a function that lists all the headers prepared so far (host, user agent, referer)?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php But you may have to send out the curl before getting the actual sent header.

Comment: that's ok, as long as i can see what i sent. looks like it's the `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` option.